# TimeCapsule connection via Ehternet

Tags: networking, ethernet, apple

I come here because I have hard time connecting my PC to my timecapsule (I was a mac user before). I tried several times with information found on forums, but without success, that is why I am coming here.
So I am using Ubuntu 16.04, linked via Ethernet to my router. My timecapsule is linked via Ethernet to the same router.
I would like to use it to access files in there, and use it as a HDD to save heavy document.
Anyone can help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the ones still looking for this:

Mount time capsule
sudo mount -t cifs //"IP Time Capsule/Namefile" -o username="Your Username",password="Your PAssword),sec=ntlm /mnt